# How do i make a nextjs app running on localhost:3000 accessable to the web?

Tags: linux, next.js, centos

To summarize my problem. I have a linux cloud server running CentOS 7 with a nextjs app running on localhost:3000. I also have a domain name, and i would like to access my nextjs app on my linux server by using my domain name on the internet.

Ive tried following these two articles, without success

https://devstudioonline.com/article/deploy-nextjs-app-with-nginx-and-pm2-on-linux-ubuntu

https://devsolo.in/posts/how-to-deploy-next-js-application-on-linux-server

Comment: Use ngrok, very easy to use tool to make local port available online via https. Method explained here: https://frontendguruji.com/blog/run-next-js-app-locally-in-https/